# Bottom zero is not working

Tags: css

I have a piece of CSS code that arranges the bottom `div` at bottom 0 and position fixed. This works perfectly but when I am resizing the window the bottom `div` is hiding the above ones (middle and top).
Here is the code:

```
.topFull{
  width:100%;
  height: 90px;
  background:#1b3f61;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.middle{
  width:100%;
  min-width:850px;
  max-width:1000px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.bottomFull{
  width: 100%;
  background:#1b3f61;
  height: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a JsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YJD2d/ Here it the fiddle, still can't understand the problem

Comment: cannot reproduce this, I tried your css on some simple html in this fullscreen fiddle, didn't notice the behavior you described, think you should provide your html too, may also be this is an issue with your browser? take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/3jEaj/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Your `.bottomFull` tag is fixed and `180px` height. So if you have a smaller screen, it will always been positioned over the other content.

You could do something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
.bottomFull{height:80px;}
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when i am resizing my window, not by using smaller screen but with my mouse, the bottomFull is staying always at the bottom of current window and hiding the topFull and middle divs above it.

Comment: And what is the desired behavior?

Comment: To not hide the above divs. I know that if a said that the bottomFull stays always at bottom: 0 then as i am resizing the window it will cover everything else above it. Maybe i can accomplished it with jquery.

Comment: You could use `%` to define `.bottomFull` height like: `height: 30%;`

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. Instead of messing around with bottomFull properties I change middle div a little bit and add

```
padding-bottom: 120px
```

now even my bottomFull div is always at bottom of window I can scroll and view middle div's contents.